# What does it risk if... I get caught looking at the pay sheet in my coworker's bag by my manager?

Tags: colleagues

What does it risk if... I get caught looking at the pay sheet in my coworker's bag by my manager ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that this would be inappropriate, there shouldn't be any reason for you to worry about what your coworkers earn, this information doesn't help you and your salary negotiations should stand on its own.

Answer (score 3):

You risk being sacked for tampering with others property and earning a reputation as someone who will steal off workmates. No one else knows what you were doing sniffing around in someones bag so it looks like a thief at work.
.

Comment: Might not be true, depending on location, and the OP has given us no information about what their location is. Some places have legal protections in place to protect workers' rights.

Comment: @nick012000 like what? Where do you get away with getting caught in the act of stealing from coworkers? I'm assuming OP isn't related or connected with the business bosses.

Comment: Looking at something and then putting it back isn't stealing, obviously, and there are places where employees can't legally be fired for arbitrary reasons.

Comment: @nick012000 then create your own answer advising the OP to tell them he wasn't stealing (which is what it looks like) he was just opening someones bag so he could read private and confidential information.

Comment: OP never said anything about stealing, though? You're putting words in his mouth. Also, I've moderator flagged this question since I don't have the Reputation to Vote to Close on this site.

Comment: @nick012000 it doesn't matter what the OP says is the motive, the obvious thought of everyone involved is that he's stealing. The explanation that he's opening someones bag and reading their confidential info isn't much better.

Comment: @nick012000 looking forward to your answer though....

Comment: @SolarMike Justin's answer sums up my thoughts pretty well. Honestly, the question's so vague that I've Voted to Close now that I've gotten to 3000 Reputation.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, Justin has a good answer, however the question asks 'What is the risk', not 'What is the probable outcome, or Best case scenario.' I just answer the question as it's posed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the location and culture.

Likely the company will do little more than tell you not to repeat this behaviour and maybe to apologize.

Your coworkers? The avenues for summary punishment are endless and obviously depend upon their temperament.